# How primefaces <p:ajax oncomplete work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, primefaces

I have his code below that will collapse other tree nodes when I expand a node.  My question is, how is primefaces doing this?  Is this a built-in feature?

```
<h:form id="mytreeform">
   <p:remoteCommand name="helloworld" update="mytree" />

   <p:tree id="mytree" value="#{treeView.root}" var="node" dynamic="true">
      <p:treeNode type="node" expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
         <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />
      </p:treeNode>
      <p:treeNode type="leaf" icon="ui-icon-document">
         <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />
      </p:treeNode>

      <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{treeView.onNodeExpand}" oncomplete="helloworld()" />

   </p:tree>
</h:form>
```

`#{treeView.onNodeExpand}` just add leaf to the node being expanded.

Comment: it might be that PrimeFaces is doing this because you tell it to. One thing that plays a key role here is your treeView bean... so please post that (why did you not do that initally?) and please post version info and why do you update the tree after an ajax event via a `remoteCommand` that does not call anything on the server? That is a weird construction. Everything should just work if you remove the `remoteCommand` and the `oncomplete="helloworld()"`

Comment: @Kukeltje you are right.  I didn't read the managebean thoroughly.  The `treeView.onNodeExpand` is storing the last node that the user was expanding.  So when the user expand another node it will collapse the stored node.

Comment: So it works now with some small changes? Shall Icreate a real answer then